# SQL Server skips RAISERROR

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, raiserror

Simple code. Very strange behaviour, triple checked this. `@filePath` and `@path` are `NVARCHAR(260)` and `@exists` is `INT`. `dbo.WriteToFile` writes a file to disk, in this case an empty file.

```
EXEC master..xp_fileexist @filePath, @exists OUTPUT
print @exists
IF @exists = 0
BEGIN
  EXEC dbo.WriteToFile N'', @path, @filename
  RAISERROR('A', 20, -1) WITH log
END
RAISERROR('B', 20, -1) WITH log
```

When I run this code for the first time and `@exists` is 0, it goes into the if block. File is created as expected. Confirmed that. But `RAISERROR` **in** the if block is **not** called. Instead only the `RAISERROR` outside the if block is called.

But if I replace the first `RAISERROR ('A')` with `PRINT 'blabla'` the print statement is called as expected.

If I replace `@exists = 0` with 1=1 and **keep** the first `RAISERROR ('A')` as is, again everything behaves correctly and the first `RAISERROR ('A')` is called.

Can someone explain this?

Oh yeah, and why does

```
print 'bla'
raiserror('bla', 20, -1) with log
```

in a brand new query window get me this:

```
bla
Meldung 2745, Ebene 16, Status 2, Zeile 3
Der Prozess mit der ID 54 hat den Benutzerfehler 50000, Schweregrad 20, ausgelöst. Dieser Prozess wird von SQL Server beendet.
bla
Meldung 2745, Ebene 16, Status 2, Zeile 3
Der Prozess mit der ID 54 hat den Benutzerfehler 50000, Schweregrad 20, ausgelöst. Dieser Prozess wird von SQL Server beendet.
```

This is 2 times the same message. Maybe my SQL server is configured incorrectly?

I will post the `WriteToFile` procedure too if you are interested, maybe it helps, I have this procedure from the web, but it works perfectly, but maybe it produces the `RAISERROR` behaviour:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.WriteToFile
 (
@String Varchar(max), --8000 in SQL Server 2000
@Path VARCHAR(255),
@Filename VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE  @objFileSystem int
                ,@objTextStream int,
        @objErrorObject int,
        @strErrorMessage Varchar(1000),
            @Command varchar(1000),
            @hr int,
        @fileAndPath varchar(80)

select @strErrorMessage='opening the File System Object'
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate  'Scripting.FileSystemObject' , @objFileSystem OUT

Select @FileAndPath=@path+'\'+@filename
if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objFileSystem , @strErrorMessage='Creating file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod   @objFileSystem   , 'CreateTextFile'
    , @objTextStream OUT, @FileAndPath,2,True

if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, 
    @strErrorMessage='writing to the file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Write', Null, @String

if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, @strErrorMessage='closing the file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Close'

if @hr<>0
    begin
    Declare 
        @Source varchar(255),
        @Description Varchar(255),
        @Helpfile Varchar(255),
        @HelpID int

    EXECUTE sp_OAGetErrorInfo  @objErrorObject, 
        @source output,@Description output,@Helpfile output,@HelpID output
    Select @strErrorMessage='Error whilst '
            +coalesce(@strErrorMessage,'doing something')
            +', '+coalesce(@Description,'')
    raiserror (@strErrorMessage,16,1)
    end
EXECUTE  sp_OADestroy @objTextStream
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @objTextStream
END
```

edit: running SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you really need a "20" error level, but please try with:

```
RAISERROR('A', 16, -1) WITH log
```